# Run JW Player on mobile web browser

Tags: youtube, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using embedded youtube videos to play on JWPlayer. But when i run my site on mobile devices(Android,Iphone,Ipad) web browser then it display videos running in youtube player not in JW Player

This is my code which i am using

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/2121212121.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container-video">
     <script type='text/javascript'>
              jwplayer("container-video").setup({
                file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5-yKhDd64s",
                width: 545,
                height: 350


   });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me where i am going wrong

Comment: We simply fall back to the default YouTube embedded player on mobile for the time being. Soon, we will actually support YouTube HTML5 mode properly in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ethan. I think JWplayer uses flash to play videos and mobile devices does not  flash in its web browser

Comment: Np. We simply only support the YouTube AS3 API right now. We are going to add support for their HTML5 API shortly though.

Answer (score -1):

Mobile devices are officially supported by JW Player, using HTML5 but not flash.

reference：
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403653-browser-device-support

Comment: Ethan already explained why YouTube videos are shown with the YouTube player. JW Player support for HTML5 on mobile devices isn't the issue.